# How to handle question where asker changes conditions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

What do I do with a question where it becomes clear the asker didn't give enough information in the first place? Scenario:

Asker asks, we answer. He won't accept any of our answers and says something like: "Well, I have conditions x and y that need to be filled also, so your solutions won't work". This he did not state in the question.

It only became clear in a comment a long way down the list, to one of the answers.

He has not updated his question after this became clear.

Flag it as

- it should be closed for another reason...
- it is very low quality This question has severe formatting or content problems?

Update his problem for him?

Comment: I'd treat it as any other Chameleon question. At some point you walk away; if the OP doesn't want to work help you help them, then don't waste your time.

Comment: If you want to close the question, then 'not enough information to diagnose the problem' is a good off-topic close reason.

Comment: I can agree it's a variant of a chameleon question. You may close this question :)

Comment: Why would you down vote a duplicate? As not only I see it, duplicate questions bring value to the community, since the asker may not know how to formulate a question, and might be hard pressed to find an already existing answer. As in my case, I did not know of the term "Chameleon Question". Someone searching for this question, will be linked to the "original" question. Good, no?

Comment: The ways of anonymous voting can be mysterious. I've offset it with an upvote.